# Loop Through Listview Checked Items

Tags: c#, loops, listview, sms

In regards to my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32025084/c-sharp-sms-sender-thru-modem) about sending SMS, I am having trouble sending the message to all selected items in the listview via checkbox.

The message will be sent to their mobile numbers which is subitem1 in the listview.

Here's my code for sending the message.

```
foreach (ListViewItem eachItem in lvNumbers.SelectedItems)
{
     //string Selected = eachItem.Text;
     string Selected =  lvNumbers.Items[Convert.ToString(eachItem)].SubItems[1].Text;
     sm.sendSMS(Selected, txtMessage.Text);
}

sm.Closes();
MessageBox.Show("Messages Sent!");
```

What Am I missing.

Here's a screenshot of the program.

[image]

Comment: What is the trouble? It doesn't explain what is the actual problem you're having

Comment: You need to wait for each sms sent after `sm.sendSMS(Selected, txtMessage.Text);` line. But not sure because you did not mention the exact issue.

Comment: You must describe the issue you are facing (error description, unwanted behavior, etc...)

Comment: When I send the message, the body of the loop isn't executed.

It goes directly to the messagebox part.

Comment: I guess `lvNumbers.SelectedItems` always empty in your case.

Comment: Windows Form. Sorry, I forgot to mention.

Comment: How sure are you it does not get executed? Have you placed a breakpoint in the body of the foreach statement? Did this breakpoint not get hit? Maybe show the full body of the method

Comment: @HariPrasad

Can't be sure since I all the items in the listview are selected via checkbox

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look for `CheckedItems` not `SelectedItems`:

```
foreach (ListViewItem eachItem in lvNumbers.CheckedItems)
{
    //string Selected =  lvNumbers.Items[Convert.ToString(eachItem)].SubItems[1].Text;
    string Selected = eachItem.SubItems[1].Text; //directly access "eachItem"
}
```

Because your items are `Checked` not selected.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final code for the send button.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cboPorts.Text.Trim()))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select COM port first.", "Err", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            txtMessage.Focus();
            return;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMessage.Text.Trim()))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Message.", "Err", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            txtMessage.Focus();
            return;
        }

        SMS sm = new SMS(cboPorts.Text);
        sm.Opens();

        MessageBox.Show(lvNumbers.CheckedItems.Count.ToString());

        foreach (ListViewItem eachItem in lvNumbers.CheckedItems)
            {

                string Selected = eachItem.SubItems[1].Text;                
                sm.sendSMS(Selected, txtMessage.Text);
            }

        sm.Closes();
        MessageBox.Show("Messages Sent.");
```

Thanks again guys..